# Algorithm to use for Binary to Int Conversion

Tags: c++, algorithm

My assignment is to use C++ to convert a string representing a binary number to an `int`.

For example,

```
int result = BinaryToInt("10110");
```

should give `result` the value `22`. Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int BinaryToInt(string s) {
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i) {
        result *= 2;
        result += s[i] - '0';
    }
    return result;
}
```

Is there any way to complete this task without using explicit loops? (The requirement is that the program doesn't include keywords like `for` or `while` and so on.) It was suggested to use a built-in algorithm, but I am not sure which one(s) to use or how to implement it.

Comment: I think even the standard stoi functions uses loops to convert from base 2 to 10 https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol

Comment: The requirement is that the program doesn't include keywords like "for" or "while" and so on.

Comment: Re: "It was suggested to use an algorithm": That is a bizarre suggestion. An "[algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithm)" is simply a sequence of steps. *Every* program uses algorithms. Either you misunderstood the suggestion, or whoever made it must be pulling your leg.

Comment: @ruakh I supect the request is more along the lines of using the built in algorithms in the standard library, rather than coding the loop yourself which is often recommended in modern C++. [Sean Parent would be proud](https://sean-parent.stlab.cc/presentations/2013-09-11-cpp-seasoning/cpp-seasoning.pdf)

Comment: That "algorithm" is called [std::bitset](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/bitset) and using `to_ulong`.

Comment: @ruakh the comment made by zdan is correct, we are supposed to use built-in algorithms.

Comment: Alternatively, the question seeks a recursive solution.

Comment: @CodeGuy7153 What's wrong with simply `return std::bitset<32>(s).to_ulong();`?  It does all the work with converting the string to its decimal equivalent.

Answer (score 4):

If you use C++11 you have [`std::stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol):

```
int num = std::stoi("10110", nullptr, 2);
```

- `"10110"` - string that you want to convert
- `2` - base from which you convert

Comment: Didn't realize `stoi` allowed you to specify a base. I'm keeping that in the back of my head.

Comment: Is there any way someone can explain why "nullptr" is being used here?

Comment: The second argument can be the address of an integer where the number of characters processed will be stored. Using `nullptr` specifies that you don't want the number of characters processed.